# How to set SASS settings to noCache = True? Using Gulp & gulp-ruby-sass

Tags: ruby, sass, gulp, gulp-ruby-sass

I'm not using compass or codekit, just Gulp to compile my SASS files. And a `.sass-cache` folder gets generated. I'd rather it not and don't mind the extra nano secs it would take to compile, because it adds too much to my quick find in Sublime Text.

In the docs for `gulp-ruby-sass` I found the option for `noCache` however I'm not sure where to set it or what the syntax is. Would you know? Somewhere in my GulpFile?

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-ruby-sass

```
noCache
Type: Boolean
Default: false
```

Here is my Gulp Task

```
gulp.task('web_css', function() {
    return sass('bower_components/sass-smacss/sass/manage.scss', { style: 'compressed' })
        .pipe(sass({ noCache: true }))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./maps'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/css/'))
});
```

Comment: Can't you just tell Sublime to ignore the directory?

Comment: @cimmanon did not know you could do that, thanks for the tip! https://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=7340

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a valid example of how to do it:

```
gulp.task('sass', function () {
  return sass('bower_components/sass-smacss/sass/manage.scss', 
      { noCache: true, style: 'compressed' }
     )
     .pipe(gulp.dest('path/to/your/css'))
  );;
});
```

When you apply the `sass` function, you have to pass your option as a parameters.

Comment: Hey thanks! Working on this now, I just edited my question with the first thing I tried, but got an `Arguments to path.join must be string` error

Comment: Ah here we go :D `return sass('bower_components/sass-smacss/sass/manage.scss', { noCache: true, style: 'compressed' })`